# if I create new class in Angular2 I have this error: TypeError: http_2.Headers is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, systemjs

*This is a bug! In v1.8 - this bug is fixed!*

I create issue in TypeScript repository: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7616

Problem:

I create simple class:
defs.ts

```
export class default_config {
    token:string
}

export var HEROES:default_config = {
    token: 'a'
};

export class HeroService {
    getHeroes() {
        return HEROES;
    }

    setToken(key) {
        HEROES.token = key;
    }
}
```

And import to app.ts:

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from "angular2/router";
import {Headers} from "angular2/http";
import {HeroService} from "./defs";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, HeroService],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello1 {{name}}</h2>
      <br>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class App {
  constructor(private http:Http, serv: HeroService) {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
    var heads = new Headers();
    console.log(heads);
  }
}
```

But in console I have error: TypeError: http_2.Headers is not a constructor

Why? Why http_2? Why headers?...

When I this code:

```
import {Headers} from "angular2/http";
import {HeroService} from "./defs";
```

replace to this:

```
import {HeroService} from "./defs";
import {Headers} from "angular2/http";
```

**all working fine!**
But I can not understand why I have this error?

Live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/nfqjRyktqnscwUc6stbY?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you should use:

```
import {Headers} from 'angular2/http';
```

instead of

```
import {Headers} from "angular2/http";
```

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Eda5ypYUcn1N5XNM0FEM?p=preview.

Comment: Hmmm, really, but why different ' and " in angular2? With " working too, but working very strange

Comment: Working with different Quotation mark is special feature or a bug?

Comment: Normally single and double quotes are similar in TypeScript / JavaScript. I wonder if it's not because you use both `"angular2/http"` and `'angular2/http'` into two different imports...

Comment: I think that I need to write a report in TypeScript support.
Such work with quotes compiler is very similar to a bug.

Comment: Yes, definitely agreed. Feel free to put a link to your report. I would be interested in knowing the cause of the problem ;-)

Comment: This bug fixed in v1.8 TS )